# Windows 10 UAP App using Boost Thread can't start on phone

Tags: multithreading, boost, windows-runtime, windows-phone, win-universal-app

I have an app which uses Boost libraries. On Desktop, the Windows UAP application works as expected, however, on phone (real phone or emulator), the app crash on start, and it is not possible to debug.

It seems the issue comes from the boost::thread library.

Here are simple steps to reproduce this issue:

- Build boost thread and date_time (date_time seems required to link) from the command line with: `b2 --with-thread --with-date_time toolset=msvc-14.0 variant=debug link=static architecture=x86 windows-api=store cxxflags="/AIC:/winrt"`. Note that "C:/winrt" is a junction to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\store\references" where platform.winmd is (since it seems required to build)
- Create a Blank C++ Windows 10 Universal app using Visual studio 2015.
- Edit Mainpage.xaml.cpp and add a call to boost::thread like: `boost::thread workerThread(workerFunc);` where "workerFunc" is whatever function you want. Add the required include file ( `#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>` ). In the link option, add boost thread lib.
- Now run the app in a phone emulator.
- Result: the app will crash at load time.

This happens on real phones with arm CPU too (with boost built with option `architecture=arm`). This issue can't be reproduced on desktop computers using the same app built for the emulator. Just run the app on your locale machine and it will work.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that Windows UAP projects link by default with library which are not available in phones, like ole32.lib. So it compiles and work on desktop, but crash on phone, and there is no information about which dll creates the issue. Furthermore, the app validation software from microsoft doesn't provide any information about that.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar issue , app works fine in desktop but fails to load in windows phone emulator. I ran the certification toolkit and found out app is using restricted api (CryptGenRandom in advapi32.dll) which boost was using. removing that particular function call resolved issue.

Comment: I expected that too, so I ran the certification test (the one proposed after a package is generated), and everything is ok. So at this point I really don't know what to do. The issue is that I don't know where to find any explicit error report for the crash which may help me find the issue.

Comment: @Mathieu Which version of boost are you using ?

Comment: We use Boost 1.60.0.

Comment: We found that building Boost using the boost command line scripts doesn't generate good libraries. It links with libraries not compatible with Windows Phones. For example, for Boost thread, it used ole32 dll which is not supported on Phones. At the end, we solved our issues by creating our own Universal Static library projects using Visual studio 2015 for each of the Boost modules we use. For some modules we had to mock a few functions to use Windows 10 API.